# How can you use an output variable when it is a storage account connection string?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I've got a powershell script in a release that gets the storage account connection string and creates an output variable. When I try to use that output variable in the next powershell script (just adding it to a key vault) it throws an error saying that "the term 'AccountName=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...".

Here's the script used to generate the connectionString variable:

```
$storageAccKey = (az storage account keys list -g $(ResourceGroup) -n $(StorageAccount) --query [0].value)
$storageAccConn = -join("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=","$(StorageAccount)",";AccountKey=",$storageAccKey,";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=connectionString;isOutput=true]$storageAccConn"
```

I verified that this produces the value I want. I have set the 'Output Variables' > 'Reference name' to "ConnectionVariable" and on the next script I've set the 'Script Arguments' to '$(ConnectionVariable.connectionString)' and try and use the value like this:

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --name $(MyConnectionString) --value "$(ConnectionVariable.connectionString)"
```

but this throws the error mentioned above. It's like it's trying to run the "$(ConnectionVariable.connectionString)" as a cmdlet. What am I doing wrong?

***Update***

I found a workaround, though I'd still be interested to know the problem. In this case I was able to just pass the storage account key as the output parameter and the next task constructed the connectionstring using the output parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. I was able to just pass the storage account key as the output parameter and the next task constructed the connectionstring using the output parameter.